# In Electron process.stderr is not defined

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to use sqlite3 nodejs add-on in my Electron app. I encountered an error while just loading the sqlite3 module. Looking at the stack trace of the crash I see that sqlite3 has several dependencies and one of them being a logging library (npmlog). This library tries to initialize some logging objects from `process.stderr`. It crashes because `process.stderr` is undefined.

When I check the value of `process.stderr` from DevConsole, I see that it's indeed undefined.

Looking at the [Electron documentation of `process` module](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/process/), I see that it's supposed to be an extended version of nodejs's `process` module. Since nodejs has `process.stderr` defined, I'm not sure why it's not defined in Electron.

Any ideas?